# How to get params in action passed via runAction in Yii2

Tags: yii2, parameter-passing, yii-actions

I used `runAction()` function to launch action within another action in the same controller.
`Yii::$app->runAction('main/goods', ['model_id' => $goods->id]);`. How to get this variable in `actionGoods()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this way

```
Yii::$app->runAction('main/goods', ['model_id' => $goods->id]);
```

In MainController

```
public function actionGoods($model_id)
{
    ..... yuor code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Good solution!